# Multilabel Text Classification NLTK

Tags: classification, nltk

I work on a classifier that has to do the following:
Classify a given small text with either one, two or even three labels (out of a source of 30 different labels).
The labels are given independently from each other, so I need the classifier to calculate the probability for all thirty labels
and just assign three with a given percentage of probability. If only one label is above that probability, then it will only assign this one,
if two are above, then it will assign those two labels.

I have a set of about 25 000 already labeled texts which can be used for training purposes.
My problem is that I can easily train my classifier to classify one label for the text, but I have no idea how to make it
label up to three labels at once. I read all the time that NLTK can do multilabeling, but I hardly find any good sources and
none of them help me with my specific problem.
I also tried scikit and textblob, but without any success.

What did I oversee? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/alvations/bayesline

Comment: You are talking about multi-label classification. There are many approaches. The simplest one is to build a separate classifier for each target label and get the respective probability for the test documents. Other approaches may capture the inter-dependence between the labels (e.g. A document may be more probable to talk about 'economy' if it also talks about 'politics').